# Drawing a DPDA for the language $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*|n_a(w)=n_b(w)\}$ in Sipser's format

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

As I know $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\mid n_a(w)=n_b(w)\}$ is a deterministic context free language. I have drawn a push dawn automata for this language in the format of Sipser as the following
[image]

However, as you may know, in Sipser's format, the transition
$$\varepsilon,$;\varepsilon$$
means that "don't read any thing from the input" and it doesn't mean "read $\varepsilon$ from the input". In Sipser's format this is a non-deterministic push down automata, since in deterministic one, we have that if there is a transition
$$\varepsilon,$;\varepsilon$$
outgoing from the state $q_1$ then it must not be an outgoing transition
$$a,$;a$ $$
from that state.

Could you please help me to draw a DPDA for that language in Sipser's format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself have found that DPDA as follows:
[image]

Comment: Good for you. $ $

Comment: OK. Seems you can actually merge states q2 and q3 into one?

Comment: @Hendrik Jan, yes. I think you are right.